# Convert OutputStream to Okio Source

Tags: kotlin, inputstream, outputstream, okio

I am trying to find elegant way to convert `OutputStream` produced by `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream)` method to Okio's `Source` / `InputStream` (needed to further manipulate data - encoding) while maintaining the data buffer.

I tried using

```
val pipe = Pipe(100)
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, Okio.buffer(pipe.sink()).outputStream())
        saveFile(File("filename"), pipe.source())
```

but this hangs on `bitmap.compress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Buffer instead http://square.github.io/okio/1.x/okio/okio/Buffer.html

```
val buffer = Buffer()
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, buffer.outputStream())
saveFile(File("filename"), buffer)
```

Pipe would assume a concurrent writer to avoid potentially blocking

http://square.github.io/okio/1.x/okio/okio/Pipe.html

> A source and a sink that are attached. The sink's output is the source's input. Typically each is accessed by its own thread: a producer thread writes data to the sink and a consumer thread reads data from the source.
>   This class uses a buffer to decouple source and sink. This buffer has a user-specified maximum size. When a producer thread outruns its consumer the buffer fills up and eventually writes to the sink will block until the consumer has caught up.

Comment: I need then `InputStream` for `javax.crypto.CipherInputStream`. I successfully got it using `saveFile(Okio.source(buffer.inputStream()))`. I hope it is a correct way to do this.